# Spring Boot Application : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I am trying to use a Simple Spring boot application to create Users and save them to the database using Hibernate but i am getting this error.

Can you please direct me to be able to solve this problem ?

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   At least one JPA metamodel must be present!   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)

My Application includes :
**Pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootHibernateInt</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

DataSource COnfiguration:

```
package com.spring.security.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        ds.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        ds.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        ds.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("spring.hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("spring.hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("spring.hibernate.show-sql", env.getProperty("spring.hibernate.show-sql"));
        properties.put("spring.hibernate.format-sql", env.getProperty("spring.hibernate.format-sql"));
        properties.put("spring.hibernate.ddl-auto", env.getProperty("spring.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager htm = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        htm.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory().getObject());
        return htm;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean lsfb = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        lsfb.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        lsfb.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        // lsfb.setAnnotatedClasses(User.class);
        lsfb.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("entitymanager.packagesToScan"));
        return lsfb;
    }
}
```

**User.java**

```
package com.spring.security.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**UserDAOImpl.java**

```
package com.spring.security.dao;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.spring.security.model.User;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDAOImpl {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public User findUser(String userName) {
        return (User) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("from User where name = " + userName);
    }

    public void createUser(User user) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .save(user);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
package com.spring.security.web;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.spring.security.dao.UserDAOImpl;
import com.spring.security.model.User;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAOImpl userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save")
    @ResponseBody
    public String create(String name) {
        try {

            User user = new User(name);

            userService.createUser(user);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return ex.getMessage();
        }
        return "User succesfully saved!";
    }

}
```

**Run.java**

```
package com.spring.security;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Run {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Run.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Application.properties**

```
################### JDBC Configuration ###############################

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/***
spring.datasource.username=***
spring.datasource.password=***

################### Hibernate Configuration ##########################

spring.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.hibernate.format-sql=true
spring.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

entitymanager.packagesToScan = com
```

Comment: Why you put the packages to scan in a property? What is the value of the property?

Comment: You don’t need any of the datasource/hibernate configuration beans you created. Why don’t you remove that whole class and try that way. Spring Boot will automatically configure the datasource and JPA.

Comment: @Jens, Added application.properties to the question.

Comment: @Strelok , If i remove the datasource config , it gives this error : Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment you can remove all the manual data source configuration as Spring Boot will auto configure it all for you. You can also use JPA repositories for what you need. Replace your UserDaoImpl class with a new repository interface:

```
@Repository
interface UserRepository implements CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
  User findByName(String name);
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save")
    @ResponseBody
    public String create(String name, String city) {
        try {

            User user = new User("JAYESH");

            userService.save(user);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return ex.getMessage();
        }
        return "User succesfully saved!";
    }

}
```

If you really really want to use Hibernate SessionFactory you can do the following:

```
@Component
public SomeClass {

  @Autowired
  private EntityManagerFactory emFactory;
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return emFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Strelok, Thanks for your helping me out with this , I am new to spring boot.
I didn't use SessionFactory and use the upper two code snippets and again got an error :  
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available.
Can you please help me further

Comment: Post your main class please

Comment: its the same as currently provided (Run.java)

Comment: It seems there were unnecessary dependencies added with conflicting versions which caused this problem , Once dependencies were fixed your solution was perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot by Default Enable Auto Configuration class for the data source, you can simply disable this by something like this.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.class,
                                HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class,DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan
public class SpringBootStarter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyBootApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This may help you :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help , its working fine now.
But since i am using spring boot , i would like spring boot to auto configure the datasource for me , Can you help me with that as well ?